# Docker: Failed to execute docker command to C:\<user_folder>

Tags: docker

I'm trying to scan a docker image using the `wss-unified-agent.jar` and `wss-unified-agent.config`. However, it seems that Docker can't create and access the folder under my `C:\<user_folder>`, thus I'm getting the following error:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                       
-------------------- Start: Docker Entity ------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[INFO] [2021-02-04 13:53:58,800 +0800] - Image 1 of 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[WARN] [2021-02-04 13:54:41,121 +0800] - CommandLineProcess - executeProcessCommand - error in execute command 'docker save 5481f8ff92d0 -o C:\<user_folder>\AppData\Local\Temp\application.tar', Exit Status 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[WARN] [2021-02-04 13:54:41,122 +0800] - Failed to execute docker command to: C:\<user_folder>\AppData\Local\Temp\application                                             
[INFO] [2021-02-04 13:54:41,124 +0800] -                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                       
-------------------- End: image-tag-sha256 -----------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please note that when using other commands, I can create a folder in the said directory.